# Populating Menu from JS Array without duplicate by JQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays, menu, append, populate

i have a problem and I could not overcome about two days.
I have an delimited string and i want to populate a menu via JQuery.
My array like this;

```
Country1,City1|Country1,City2|Country2,City1|Country3,City1|Country3,City2|Country3,City3
```

and i want to use [this](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex1/flexdropdown.htm) menu structure by using JQuery `append` function (or any other suggested way)
I mean, when the user hover over my menu trigger a menu will pop up and all Countries will be shown and each one has own sub menu elements (Cities).
i would like to point that, how many Countries exist and each Contry has how many cities are unknown.
I used `unique` function to eleminate duplicated Countries but i cound not put Cities into Countries.

Thanks right now..

Comment: Is your array actually a pipe-delimited string, or a real array?

Comment: @nrabinowitz i'am sorry it is not array yet :) pipe-delimited string

Comment: jQuery.unique() doesn't work on arrays of strings or numbers.

Comment: @mblase75 i've tried to split this string and take Countries as array then i used unique function to delete duplicated countries (i succeed) but i couldn't put cities on countries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this working example: http://jsfiddle.net/nrabinowitz/FDWgF/

You first need to collect the cities for each country in an object with the country names as keys, then iterate through that object to create your list:

```
var data = "Country1,City1|Country1,City2|Country2,City1|Country3,City1|Country3,City2|Country3,City3";

// split into country/city pairs
data = data.split('|');

var countries = {},
    pair, country, city;

for (var x=0; x<data.length; x++) {
    // get pair as an array
    pair = data[x].split(',');
    country = pair[0];
    city = pair[1];
    // make sure the country is in our object
    if (!(country in countries)) {
        countries[country] = []
    }
    // add the city to the list for that country
    countries[country].push(city);
}

// now get the values out of the object
$.each(countries, function(country, cities) {
    var $country = $('<li>' + country + '<ul></ul></li>');
    // append each city to sub-list
    $.each(cities, function(i, city) {
        $('ul', $country)
            .append('<li>' + city + '</li>')
    });
    // now append the whole thing to the country list
    $('#countries').append($country);
});
```

Comment: For what it's worth: http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/FDWgF/1/ -- same loop, different HTML build. I don't like using `$.each` when a plain old `for` loop will do.

Comment: Well, I've always been told (mostly by jslint :) that you need to wrap `for (x in y)` loops with a conditional `if (y.hasOwnProperty(x))` statement. This always seems like a pain to me. I also like the scope control the inner function of `.each()` provides. But it's really just personal preference.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/FDWgF/2/ -- adds some unrequested sorting of countries and cities. Sadly `Object.keys` isn't universally supported, so an extra array was needed.

Comment: @ mblase75, city lists should be warpped be countries' list element but in your fiddle they are self warpped. How can i correct this issue? I mean should be like this <li><a href"#">Country</a><ul><li><a href="#">City</a></li></ul></li>

Answer (score 0):

your array should be a multi-dimensional array like this:

```
var countries = {
"country1":["city1", "city2"],
"country2":["city1"],
"counrty3":["city2", "city2"]
};
```

Then you will not have duplicate countries, then you should loop through the array with `for in` and populate the menu that way

```
var options = "";
foreach(countries as country)
{
    foreach(country as city)
    {
        options += "<option value=" + city+ ">"+ city+ "</options>";
    }
}
$("#cities").html(options)
<select id="cities">
</select>
```

Comment: this is essentially the same solution suggested by nrabinowitz

Comment: Except that your object values ought to be arrays, not sub-objects, right?

Comment: does it make any practical difference?

Comment: Well, for one thing, your code isn't syntactically correct - `{city1, city2}` is a syntax error in Javascript. It's also usually easier to iterate through an array.

Comment: suggestion noted, only thing I would say is he asked for a select box, do you see any problems with the above?